Azure DevOps pipeline for a repo with multiple solutions with multiple projects and dependencies on each other
I'm new to Azure DevOps. I have a repo that contains multiple solutions and each solution contains multiple projects. These projects have dependencies on each other. Projects are targeting .NET 4.7.1. Building all of them in order, I get a package for a WPF application.
I would like to create one Azure YAML pipeline but I'm not sure about the correct way.
This is my pipeline at the moment:
trigger:
  - none
#- desarrollo

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildPlatform: 'x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: 'Folder1/Solution_A.sln'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'Folder1/Solution_A.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:AzureBuild=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: MSBuild@1
  inputs:
   solution: 'Folder2/Solution_B/Project_B1.csproj'
   msbuildArguments: '/p:AzureBuild=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
   platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
   configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\release\**'
    flattenFolders: false
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'GicoopPlus'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

Solution_B.Project_B1 has a dependency on the project Solution_A.Project_A1 and Solution_A.Project_A1 has a dependency on Solution_A.Project_A2.
When running the pipeline, I get an error on MsBuild@1 task because it has not found Solution_A.Project_A2.dll.
What is the best way to do I need?

Would you consider publishing the dependency generated by Solution_A.Project_A1 to Azure Artifacts for one time?
You may restore that dependency from that feed before building Solution_B.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: 'Solution_B.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '$(ProjectName)/$(ProjectScopeFeed-NuGet)'

Thus, you don't have to build the two solutions together every time.

Finally, the pipeline is working. I had an error because of one project was not configured for x64 platform. And the outputh of the project was \bin\release but \bin\x64\release where the other project was find it.

Hi CiscoCabe, Much appreciate for your taking time to share the findings and solution to configure the platform.

Would you consider it as Resolved, which may help others with similar issues? Thx and cheers.
